# Deserialize json object with dynamic items in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I've got the following json document:

```
{
  "name": "bert",
  "Bikes": {
    "Bike1": {
      "value": 1000,
      "type": "Trek"
    },
    "Bike2": {
      "value": 2000,
      "type": "Canyon"
    }
  }
}
```

With potentially other bikes like Bike3...BikeN. I want to deserialize to C# objects. Problem is that in the deserialization step the bikes data is completely lost, resulting in a null Bikes collection.

Code to reproduce:

```
[Test]
public void FirstCityJsonParsingTest()
{
    var file = @"./testdata/test.json";
    var json = File.ReadAllText(file);

    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
    Assert.IsTrue(res.Name == "bert");
    // next line is failing, because res.Bikes is null...
    Assert.IsTrue(res.Bikes.Count == 2);
}

public class Bike
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

To fix this problem a change in the used model is necessary. But what change is needed here to fill the bikes data correctly?

Note: Changing the input document is not an option (as it's a spec)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's failing"? What's the count? Did the Person object not get a Bikes property populated? Please be explicit in describing what's happening.

Comment: `Bikes` isn't an array, look at `Dictionary<string, Bike>` structure

Comment: try this `    public class Bike1
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bike2
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bikes
    {
        public Bike1 Bike1 { get; set; }
        public Bike2 Bike2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Bikes Bikes { get; set; }
    }` @bertt

Comment: Can you change the JSON document to have "Bikes" as an array (`[ ]`) instead of object (`{ }`)? You then also have to move the Id ("Bike1") into the bike object as "id" property

Comment: @HansKeﬆing changing the input json is not an option in this case (because spec).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code structure is not reflecting your json. Common approach to deserializing json with dynamic property names is to use `Dictionary<string, ...>` (supported both by `Json.NET` and `System.Text.Json`). Try the following:

```
public class Bike
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

`Person.Bikes` should be changed to `Dictionary<string, Bike>` (also `Bike.Id` property is not needed) cause `Bikes` json element is not an array but object.