# How to deserialize json to C# class with arbitrary number of values and attributes

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to consume some JSON files, which could contains a arbitrary number of child values.

By simplifying the JSON, I get something like:

```
{
"timestamp":1710415627927,
"parent":{
  "id":"680867",
  "key":"XXX",
  "childs":{
     "customchild_1":{
        "value":"DIS",
        "id":"16805"
     },
    "customchild_2":null,
    "customchild_3":null,
    "customchild_4":[
        "01 (CHIL-172)"
     ],
    "customchild_5":[
        "02 (CHIL-44553)"
     ],
    "customchild_6":{
        "value":"Achievement",
        "id":"13425",
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Of course, each file could have different number of `customfield_xxx` attributes, and values associated can be (generally) above 3 kind of values (`id` / `value`, `[]` or `null`)

I try to create a first class for parent

```
public class parent
{
   public Dictionary<object, List<customchild>> customchilds { get; set; }
...
}

public class customchild
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

problem is that I don't know if it will work for all and on my main process, how I can :

- count the number of customchild attributes in my JSON
- access the Nth customchild ?

Comment: Personally I would recommend to find person who designed such inconsistent JSON file and use a baseball bat to explain why this is not ideal)

Comment: As for real answer - your current JSON have two problems you need to tackle - first one is the "dynamic" property names which you have already figured out by using dictionary (though property name in class should match one from JSON - `customchilds` -> `childs`), which is a [quite common approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325842/2501279) for such things

Comment: The second problem is that you value in the dictionary can be either array or object, there are multiple ways to handle this - for example via custom converter [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008819/2501279)

Comment: What library do you use to handle JSON?

Comment: What serializer are you using?  System.Text.Json or Json.NET?  If the former, honestly I might just declare `childs` to be a `public Dictionary<string, object> childs { get; set; }` and add `new ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter() { UnknownNumberFormat  = UnknownNumberFormat.Dictionary }` to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`, where `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to [C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182).

Comment: Dear all,
thank you for your quick answer.
problem is that the json is provide by an external tool (I've just simplified it for the sample).
I'm using using Newtonsoft.Json for the deserializer.
and indeed, I think using dictionary

Comment: If you are using Json.NET, I would go with `DictionaryConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31250524) by Anish Patel to [Deserialize JSON recursively to IDictionary<string,object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11561597).  I.e. `[JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryConverter))] public Dictionary<string, object> Childs { get; set; } = new();`.

Comment: One note -- `DictionaryConverter` can be simplified by eliminating all the `Write()` methods.  Instead override `CanWrite` and return false as shown in [How to use default serialization in a custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616648/3744182).

Comment: Does [Deserialize JSON recursively to IDictionary<string,object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11561597) answer your question?

Comment: Dear all,
thank you for all your feedback. I'm new in C# and I will try to test all proposed solution.
I will let you know
many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Package to deserialize JSON as a parent object. From there, you can access the count of custom child attributes using `parentObject.ParentDetails.Customchilds.Count`.

It's functioning smoothly in my compiler.

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class Parent
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("parent")]
        public ParentDetails ParentDetails { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ParentDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("childs")]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Customchilds { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Customchild
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
                ""timestamp"": 1710415627927,
                ""parent"": {
                    ""id"": ""680867"",
                    ""key"": ""XXX"",
                    ""childs"": {
                        ""customchild_1"": {
                            ""value"": ""DIS"",
                            ""id"": ""16805""
                        },
                        ""customchild_2"": null,
                        ""customchild_3"": null,
                        ""customchild_4"": [
                            ""01 (CHIL-172)""
                        ],
                        ""customchild_5"": [
                            ""02 (CHIL-44553)""
                        ],
                        ""customchild_6"": {
                            ""value"": ""Achievement"",
                            ""id"": ""13425""
                        },
                        
                    }
                }
            }";
    
            // Deserialize JSON
            Parent parentObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
    
            // Count the number of customchild attributes
            int numberOfCustomchilds = parentObject.ParentDetails.Customchilds.Count;
      }
    }
```